# Simple app sending "Hello world!" to facebook messenger group

Tags: facebook, api, messenger

I'm trying to create simple aplication that will send me messege every day for example it can be `"Hello world!"`. Is it even possible for facebook messenger extension to send message without being called? Where should I start? I mentioning about messenger extension because I would like this app to send message to group chat.

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Messenger API is for communication between a user and a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the comments: You can only send messages from pages to users (who contacted the Page first). There is no other API for user to user communication, or for communication in groups.